# Fixed width row, dynamicaly sized columns, with break word wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a series of rows with labels and values like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="rowName">thing 1</div>
    <div class="rowValue">325,000</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="rowName">thing 2 that is longer</div>
    <div class="rowValue">4,000</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="rowName">THING_3_NO_SPACE</div>
    <div class="rowValue">150</div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle to see what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/

My problem is if the label is a lengthy single word like THING_4 up there then it will push the value out beyond the width of the outer container.

It would be fine to wrap the label to the next line, or even hide the overflow, but I cannot achieve either in a reasonable way.  I can set it to use table-layout:fixed and then the left column doesn't push the right, but only if I set explicit widths on the right column which is not practical since those can contain small to large numbers.

I am not married to the display:table and display:table-cell that's used on the divs in the jsfiddle so if the desired appearance can be achieved without that then I'm all for it.  I only used display:table to make the left column smaller when the right column is larger (so it's better than it was when long content would overlap the value), but it doesn't work if there's no word break.

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the problem with what's in the fiddle?

Comment: Hmm, I shouldn't have had that max-width in .rowName since the value widths vary so dramatically.  Here's one without that which shows the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/5/

Comment: Interestingly the max-width does what I want in firefox and chrome but I think it's not to spec so I'm afraid it'll break in later versions; supposedly max-width only applies to block elements, whereas these are table-cell.  Even though it's set to a max of 100px the last box is actually 119 pixels, seemingly doing exactly what I want: making the right-most cell as big as it needs to be to show the content and the left cell gets the rest.  If only I could find the right way to do that instead of relying on something not working quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did wind up getting this how I want it, except for the sad fact that I had to switch the order of the "columns" in the HTML so that float works how I'd expect.  Having to change the HTML structure to accommodate styling makes me sad, but I guess that's the way the real world works right now.

So I changed the order of the value and the label, floated the value to the right, removed all the display:table junk and it works ok.  Here's an updated fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/10/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">325,000</div>
    <div class="left">thing 1</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">4,000</div>
    <div class="left">thing 2 that is longer</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">150</div>
    <div class="left">THING_3_NO_SPACE_IN_HERE</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 150px;    
}
.wrapper, .right, .left {
}
.right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.left {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Did not read the last part, sorry.

Here you go
http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/1/

```
display:tabel-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

**here, forget that stuff up top, what about this?** http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/2/

Another updated idea http://jsfiddle.net/YYUg6/4/

Comment: Hi Web Owl.  Thanks for your input.  The problem with these is that the labels and values are on separate rows.  Instead, the label and its value should be on the same row together.